# How can I install dropbox in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

I am a complete novice to Linux.

I am unable to install dropbox; when on dropbox download site the .deb 64 bit package downloads but won't install. If I click <kbd>install</kbd> it will ask if I wish to remove it, but if I click <kbd>remove</kbd> it won't!

Comment: Follow the instructions at https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux. If something fails, edit your question to clearly explain exactly what you did, exactly why you believe that it did not work, and the complete error messages (if any).

Comment: cheers managed using dropbox headless install via command line; I can now access my dropbox account from my home directory; it looks like the downloadable package is obsolete. thanks for taking time to reply

Answer (score 1):

Install Dropbox from the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

I have installed this on a number of 18.04 machines with absolutely no problems whatever. It also automatically adds an icon to the top bar which goes directly to your Dropbox folder or allow you to load the Dropbox website.

There is no further configuration required. It is designed for the job.

Comment: funny enough Graham that's what I was expecting to find, but when I searched ubuntu software for dropbox it didn't' show up!problem solved anyway although the icon would have been nice thanks for your time